# Swift 4+ instantiating a class variable that conforms to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I like to create a class, in my case a UIView, that conforms to a protocol, I then want to send that variable to a function. I have the following code:

```
protocol MyProtocol{
    var aValue:Int{ get set }
}

func doSomething( myView:UIView & MyProtocol){
    print( "a Value:\(myView.aValue )")
}


let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100 )
var testView:UIView & MyProtocol = UIView(frame: rect ) as! UIView & MyProtocol
testView.aValue = 5

doSomething(myView: testView)
```

This code compiles but when I run it I get an error as testView can not be created. Can this be done? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because a `UIView` doesn't conform to the protocol.  You need to create a custom `UIView` subclass that does:

```
class CustomView : UIView, MyProtocol {
    var aValue = 0
}

var testView: UIView & MyProtocol = CustomView(frame: rect )
testView.aValue = 5

doSomething(testView: testView)
```

**Output:**

> ```
> a Value:5
> ```

---

The protocol describes the interface that the instance will provide, but it doesn't allocate the storage for the new properties.

Comment: Thanks, I created a local class, that conforms to the protocol and then use that class to instantiate the variable and pass that to the function.